# Debugging Angular 2 / Ionic 2 using webpack in the browser

Tags: angularjs, ipad, ionic-framework, safari, ionic2

Ok, so I trying to debug an Ionic 2 app in my iPad. The bug is that the PDF reader isn't working, but my main concern at the moment is getting my debugging on the iPad up and running.

Using the Developer menu item in Safari, I can see my iPad via its IP address and see console logs, element, resources, lock stock. I have even learned how to set breakpoints — how clever is that?

I have the problem now, however, that also applies to the desktop developer tools. How do I debug a webpack application in the browser? It turns all of my functions into "text" so it's not immediately apparent how to step through the code, for example.

I'm sure it has something to do with sourcemaps...am I missing something entirely basic?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack puts the source maps in the file:// domain rather than the localhost so I guess this is where your confusion stems from.

Now depending on the version of ionic app scripts the structure may vary.

0.44 and above has the full path of the file in a huge list with the node modules used.

Below 0.44 has a folder called . and inside it all app related source maps(without the node modules)